func argument with an Array of mixed types (protocol), then call a static method of the protocol
Here are my structures (I can have lot more, that why I need a generic way to do with MyProtocol):
protocol MyCustomCodable {
    static func buildQuery()
}

struct A: MyCustomCodable {
    ...
}

struct B: MyCustomCodable {
    ...
}

...

Then, my problem: I have a code somewhere that I apply on a group of them:
    func updateAllData(customCodableArrays: [[some MyCustomCodable]]) {
        for customCodableArray in customCodableArrays {
            type(of: dbCodablesArray).Element.buildQuery()
        }
    }

    let As: [A] = [A(), A()]
    let Bs: [B] = [] // some arrays can be empty ! That's why buildQuery is static.

    updateAllData([As, Bs])

But here, Swift is complaining that in the call to updateAllData, B cannot be converted to A.
I also tried something like this:
    func updateAllData(customCodableArrays: [some MyCustomCodable]...) {
        for customCodableArray in customCodableArrays {
            type(of: dbCodablesArray).Element.buildQuery()
        }
    }

    let As: [A] = [A(), A()]
    let Bs: [B] = []

    updateAllData([As, Bs])

But 'some' seems not allowed on variadic.
I tried with any (or without any, since it is implicit):
    func updateAllData(customCodableArrays: [[any MyCustomCodable]]) {
        for customCodableArray in customCodableArrays {
            type(of: dbCodablesArray).Element.buildQuery()
        }
    }

    let As: [A] = [A(), A()]
    let Bs: [B] = []

    updateAllData([As, Bs])

But here, it's the call to updateAllData which fails because "Static member 'updateAllData' cannot be used on protocol metatype '(any MyCustomCodable).Type'"
The only solution I found was to pass arrays through individual arguments to updateAllData, with some keyword. But that's not a valid solution since I don't know how much tables I will need, and it enforce me to duplicate (more or less) the code for each of them (I cannot simply iterate on all arrays).
... I don't see how to solve my problem... Please, help !
I tried using any, using some, using variadic, using Any, or casting.

Does the contents of the arrays actually matter? How about just updateAllData(A.self, B.self)? What does buildQuery do? Does it not return a value and only do side effects? To solve the actual problem you'd need a parameter pack, but I'm asking these questions anyway because you might be heading down the wrong direction.

buildQuery is implemented in an extension of MyCustomCodable and build an SQL query based on the structure fields.
The content of the array does not matter (it's just that it's what I have as original input). I tried to pass the type instead of the array instance (extracting it from the array), but that systematically raise the exact same problem where the retrieved type is any, and block the usage of buildQuery.
If I provide separate arguments as you suggest, it works. But as mentioned, I don't know how much arguments I will need...

In fact I could have simplified the question on how to call a static method of the protocol when having a type any protocol...
I understand what means any, but I don't understand why it implies so strong constraints in the language.

So buildQuery will return the same result for every instance of A since it’s a static method?

So buildQuery actually returns something? And I assume in updateAllData you want to get all the things that all the buildQuerys return, and put them into an array or something like that?

buildQuery create a query mixing the data from all structures (could not be done separately) and run it. It returns nothing.

Maybe add an example because I don't understand what it's doing? "mixing the data", what does that mean, what data are you accessing from a static method?

You're right, I'm mixing things, the real buildQuery is returning elements to build a query, regarding the fiels name and type of of the structure type. Then updateAll process them together to create and run a global query.
... but I don't think this is revenant for the current problem. The issue I encounter is something I encountered a lot of time since I use protocols (not specific to this use case) and where I never found a satisfying solution.

You can also use parameter packs to do this.
func updateAllData<each T: MyCustomCodable>(customCodableArrays: repeat [each T]) {
    repeat type(of: each customCodableArrays).Element.buildQuery()
}

updateAllData(customCodableArrays: As, Bs)

or if the contents of the arrays don't matter, take the metatypes directly:
func updateAllData<each T: MyCustomCodable>(types: repeat (each T).Type) {
    repeat (each types).buildQuery()
}

updateAllData(types: A.self, B.self)


If buildQuery returns something, say, a Query, you can collect all of them in an array like this:
func updateAllData<each T: MyCustomCodable>(types: repeat (each T).Type) {
    var queries = [Query]()
    repeat array.append((each types).buildQuery())
}


Hi I didn’t know this syntax ! It is quite complex but the solution does not imply to add a protocol and array extension. Thanks !

Your fundamental problem is that [[some MyCustomCodable]] defines a two dimensional array where all elements must be of the same type (that conforms to MyCustomCodable). This is why you can't mix arrays of type [A] and [B]. The alternative [[any MyCustomCodable]] defines a two dimensional array of which any element can be of any type that conforms to the protocol. This is no good because the expression type(of: MyCustomCodable).Element.buildQuery() has to choose a particular implementation of the static function and it can't because the elements can all be different conforming types.
I have a different approach which is a little more work but has other advantages.
Your protocol remains the same but you define another protocol for collections of MyCustomCodable which conforms to Collection and the elements must be constrained to conform to MyCustomCodable. i.e.
protocol MyCustomCodable {
    static func buildQuery()
}

protocol MyCustomCodableCollection: Collection 
where Element: MyCustomCodable 
{
    func buildQuery()
}

It has a member function called buildQuery()
Then you make Array conform to MyCustomCodableCollection which is actually really straight forward because Array is already a Collection. You can implement it like this:
extension Array: MyCustomCodableCollection where Element: MyCustomCodable
{
    func buildQuery() 
    {
        Element.buildQuery()
    }
}

Your update function then looks like this:
func updateAllData(customCodableArrays: [any MyCustomCodableCollection]) {
    for customCodableArray in customCodableArrays {
        customCodableArray.buildQuery()
    }
}

The reason I say it has other advantages is because (depending on what buildQuery() should do), you may be able to shift that code in the static function to code in the function on the relevant array type or use generic functions or some other trick to do away with the static function on each type.

Ho ! Great solution !!! I'll try this one !

I works !
I tried previously to extend directly Array like this:
extension Array where Element: MyCustomCodable {     func buildQuery() -> QueryStructure {         Element.buildQuery()     } }
But it was raising the same issue when trying to call it... I understand what was the issue now. Thanks very much

@GuillaumePELOUAS Also check out Sweeper's answer. Parameter packs are a fairly recent feature and may be a better solution depending on your use-case.
